# Unable to Download Build Agent for TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I am trying to download Build agent from the TFS 2017 using the Download button in below window.

[image: Get Agent]

But when I click on the button, I get below error message.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/53052789/caeb528e-9c6b-11e6-8b55-17a88d067ed2.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ%2F20170302%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170302T055455Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=e4d0d614b710c023adf2fc3754be068b37d7f11b0809fb6e4b0404bd59fa3db3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dvsts-agent-win7-x64-2.105.7.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`

Does this have anything to do my TFS settings/Access/Configurations or the site is actually down?

Comment: It's more likely to have to do with your internet access than anything else. Are you behind an especially restrictive corporate firewall?

Comment: @DanielMann I guess this is the reason. How to get around this? I tried disabling the Firewall on my computer but still the issue is same.

Comment: When you click the Download button, it will go to this page: "https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases/tag/v2.105.7" to download the "vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.105.7.zip" file. Try to connect to this site from browser directly and download the agent to install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get the agent from the website below:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=829054